# How to keep the rails nested resource route url when model save fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Summary:**

I have a nested attribute. I go to route:

```
/customers/:id/credit_cards/new
```

On the create action, save fails, code does

```
render :new
```

This pushes the URL to:

```
/credit_cards/new
```

How do I make sure the url stays with the customer route?

**Details:**

I want to use the following routes:

```
# Credit cards should be associated with a customer except
# potentially on initial creation:
resources :customers do
  resources :credit_cards, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show]
end
# Allow creating a credit card but selecting
resources :credit_cards, only: [:new, :create]
```

Basically a nested route for when a customer exists and a non-nested route for when I can create and assign a customer in the same view.

I have a single controller at

```
app/controller/credit_cards_controller.rb
```

In the new and create action I check if I have a customer ID or not

```
before_action :set_credit_card, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_customer, only: [:index, :show, :create, :new, :edit, :update]

# GET /credit_cards/new                                                                                                                                  
def new
  @credit_card = if @customer
                   @customer.credit_cards.build rescue CreditCard.new
                 else
                   CreditCard.new
                 end
end

def create
  @credit_card = CreditCard.new(credit_card_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @credit_card &&  @credit_card.save
      format.html { redirect_to on_new_or_update_redirect_location, notice: 'Credit card was successfully created.' }
    else
      # HERE IS THE ISSUE: Figure out how to make sure the url stays as /customers/:id/credit_cards/new instead of /credit_cards/new                                                                 
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

When there is a validation failure, it re-renders the view, but pushes the URL to

```
credit_cards/new
```

So I no longer am in the correct URL and customer_id is no longer a parameter.  I assume if I can pass the customer_id it will do the right thing, but I have not found how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because your form is posting to `/credit_cards`, rather than to `/customers/:id/credit_cards`.

Change your form to look something like this:

```
<%= form_for [@customer, @credit_card] do -%>
  ... etc...
<%= end %>
```

That should handle either case - whether the @customer is defined or not. It will then post to `customer_credit_cards_path(@customer)` if the customer is defined, or `credit_card_path` if customer is not defined. Be sure to set the `@customer` variable in your `create` action. This way when you `render :new` it will render the form with the @customer variable.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.